# Define list of objects in models.py in postgeSQL & Django-rest project

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I mostly work with **Node.js & MongoDB** and I am pretty new to SQL dbs especially **postgreSQL** I am writing an application that makes use of [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) & **postgreSQL** as a DB.

This is how my data structure as .json should look like.

```
{
  id: "19eea956-34e5-11eb-adc1-0242ac120002"
  picture: [{
   url: "",
   mimeType: ""
  }, 
  {
   url: "",
   mimeType: ""
  }]
}
```

For the above data I am currently writing `models.py` which looks like as follows.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

    class Picture(models.Model):
      url = models.CharField()
      mimeType = models.CharField()

    class A(models.Model):
        id = models.CharField(max_length=120, primary_key=True)
        picture = ArrayField(Picture)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.id
```

What I am trying to do in my `models.py` is to have picture as an `Array of Objects` or in python terminology `List of Dictionaries`.

I read about ArrayField in postgreSQL but unable to find any example about how to define `Array of Objects` in `models.py`, any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Would be great if those downvoting the Question would highlight the reason for the same, I an unable to find any workaround for my problem and also highlighted my effort I tried using ArrayField , also HStoreField but still I don't how things work with postgeSQL & Django, so please consider me a newbie working on this stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relational databases relations are defined by Foreign Keys and different tables. Tables are represented by Django's models, but the programmer should work from the model side of things and think of the database as the object persistence (storage of the state of an object).

Fields should as a rule be single values, not containers. Explaining why distracts too much from the problem at hand, but here's the [in-depth info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

In this case, you have two entities, let's call A "Gallery" for clarity. A Gallery object has 1 or more pictures. A picture can be associated with 1 gallery (business rule). There are 2 properties associated with the image: url and mime type.

Now there's several ways to deal with images and that depends whether the image is [uploaded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/) or really a [URL to a remote image](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#urlfield).

I'm going to pick the second option for brevity:

```py
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Gallery(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class Picture(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    mime_type = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pictures')
```

This creates the correct relation for the image in a way that is preferred by both Django and relational databases.

Now we need to serialize the picture to just the url and mime type field:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Picture, Gallery

class PictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Picture
        fields = ['mime_type', 'url']
```

Continuing, we need to nest the pictures into the gallery:

```py
class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pictures = PictureSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields = ['id', 'pictures']
```

And this should do the trick.

The reason people downvoted is most likely because this is a Q&A site and your scope as demonstrated by my answer is far too big for that. I've given you some handles to work with, but it's best you hit the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/) to get a basic sense of models, followed by the [DRF counterpart](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Melvyn I was also wondering I should have thought more in terms of tables then json no worries thanks for writing :)